# how to escape the < <() idiom in perl

Tags: bash, perl, backticks

I have a system command which i am trying to execute, but it gives me error "Syntax error: redirection unexpected"

Trying command:

```
datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 < <(tail -n +2 yourfile | sort -t, -k1,2) | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6
```

I tried readpipe and also escaped the < <  with \< \<, but doesn't work.

below command doesn't work ==>

```
`datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 \< \<(tail -n +2 yourfile | sort -t, -k1,2) | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6`
```

Comment: The only four special characters in double-quoted string literals (including backticks) are: `\ `, `$`, `@` and the delimiter(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks aka `readpipe` expect a command passed to `sh` (or `cmd` in Windows).
You appear to have a `bash` command rather than a `sh` command. Fixed:

```
`bash -c 'datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 < <(tail -n +2 yourfile | sort -t, -k1,2) | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6'`
```

If you had vars to interpolate, it would look like

```
use String::ShellQuote ( shell_quote );

my $qfn = '...';
my $tail_cmd = shell_quote('tail', '-n', '+2', $qfn);
my $bash_cmd = "datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 < <( $tail_cmd | sort -t, -k1,2 ) | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6";
my $sh_cmd = shell_quote('bash', '-c', $bash_cmd);
`$sh_cmd`
```

---

As @chepner noticed, the `bash` command can be converted into a simpler command that's compatible with `sh`. This reduces the first snippet to the following:

```
`tail -n +2 yourfile | sort -t, -k1,2 | datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6'`
```

This doesn't help us get away from using `shell_quote` in the second snippet, but it does reduce it it the following:

```
use String::ShellQuote ( shell_quote );

my $qfn = '...';
my $tail_cmd = shell_quote('tail', '-n', '+2', $qfn);
my $sh_cmd = "$tail_cmd | sort -t, -k1,2 | datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6";
`$sh_cmd`
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't even bother using process substitution here. Just use an ordinary pipeline:

```
`tail -n +2 yourfile | sort -t, -k1,2 | datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6`
```

Process substitution is most useful when a command (like `datamash`) needs to run in the current shell, or when you want to feed the output of one command to another command that only reads from a named file, not its standard input. Neither case applies here.